# Laravel Eloquent : one to many relationship with distinct

Tags: laravel, eloquent, greatest-n-per-group, one-to-many, eloquent-relationship

Need to get distinct row.

Is there any way in laravel eloquent to avoid the duplication of data.
Need to get unique users after joining with image table.

Now, I'm getting the same users, need to avoid the repetition of the same user.

Model Image

```
public function user()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
}
```

User Table

```
id | name
---------
| 1| Joe
| 2| Ben
| 3| Don
```

Image Table

```
id  |   name | user_id
---------------------
| 1 |  1.png |    3
| 2 |  2.png |    1
| 3 |  3.png |    1
| 4 |  4.png |    2
```

join using eloquent :

```
Image::with('user')->orderBy('id', 'desc')->paginate(10);
```

Required Output

```
"data": [
    {
        "id": 4,
        "name": "4.png",
        "user_id": 2,
        "user": {
            "id": 2,
            "name": "Ben",
        }
    },
    {
        "id": 3,
        "name": "3.png",
        "user_id": 1,
        "user": {
            "id": 1,
            "name": "Joe",
        }
    },
    {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "1.png",
        "user_id": 3,
        "user": {
            "id": 3,
            "name": "Don",
        }
    },
],
```

Comment: there actually is a `distinct()` function you can use.

Comment: @Aless55 I tried different methods using distinct, doesn't work.

Comment: Please consider, answer as accepted or up vote or down vote

Answer (score 0):

To get unique results from Eloquent call **unique()** method at end of the method chain.

```
Image::with('user')
      ->orderBy('id', 'desc') 
      ->paginate(10)
      ->unique() // Like this
```

If above method is not working try below.

```
Image::with('user')
      ->orderBy('id', 'desc') 
      ->paginate(10)
      ->unique()
      ->values()
```

Comment: I have added one more thing in answer, Now try again.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want all the users and only one of the images per user. You could do something like the following to add an image relationship to user model:

```php
    public function image()
    {
        return $this->hasOne('App\Image')->orderBy('id', 'desc');
    }
```

Then you would access this data like `User::has('image')->with('image')`;

Comment: I need to make a distinct on "user_id", is there any way in laravel eloquent to achieve it?

Comment: It almost work, but I have to get result based on the latest image. By doing it in your way the result will be based on the users. Actually in the desired output it must be in descending, I have corrected it

Comment: This should get you the latest image per user, I assumed you only wanted one image per user. Is it working for you now or do you still need help? Feel free to add your current code if you need help still.

Answer (score 0):

To get latest image for each user you can use a self join like

Schema

```
CREATE TABLE users
    (`id` int, `name` varchar(3))
;
    
INSERT INTO users
    (`id`, `name`)
VALUES
    (1, 'Joe'),
    (2, 'Ben'),
    (3, 'Don')
;

CREATE TABLE images
    (`id` int, `name` varchar(5), `user_id` int)
;
    
INSERT INTO images
    (`id`, `name`, `user_id`)
VALUES
    (1, '1.png', 3),
    (2, '2.png', 1),
    (3, '3.png', 1),
    (4, '4.png', 2)
;
```

Query

```
select a.*, u.*
from images a
left join images b on a.user_id = b.user_id
  and a.id < b.id
join users u on u.id = a.user_id
where b.user_id is null
order by a.id desc
```

Query Builder

```
DB::table('images as a')
  ->select('a.*, u.*')
  ->leftJoin('images as b', function ($join) {
        $join->on('a.user_id', '=', 'b.user_id')
             ->whereRaw(DB::raw('a.id < b.id'));
   })
  ->join('users as u', 'u.id', '=', 'a.user_id' )
  ->whereNull('b.user_id')
  ->orderBy('a.id', 'desc')
  ->get();
```

[DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/70b0b3/1)